# Text formatting, how to generate everything not in plain text

Tags: formatting, verbatim

I want to put some text in latex, which looks like

```
{
            "wow": 15,  
            "nice": 1
        },
        {
            "wow": 24,  
            "nice": 1
        },
```

But If i generate it I get everything in plain text like:

```
”wow”: 15,  ”nice”: 1 , ”wow”: 24,  ”nice”: 1 ,
```

How to get it how I wanted to look like. I maybe I should use something like parabox? Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `verbatim` environment or even packages for source code inclusion like `listings` or `minted`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I used listings and it is working, but one thing. I am writing some comments near code(its is JSON) and it has my country symbols. And they are all putted randomly. For example it should be išėjo and it is written šėijo. Maybe you could advice me something?

Comment: Use listings with a modern engine that can hanle utf8, for example LuaTeX or XeLaTeX. Apart from that, this is a new question.

Comment: @Johannes_B should I open new question? Btw I am using XelateX

Comment: Yes, please do so. Add a small example that show the behaviour.

Comment: @Johannes_B I opened new question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288173/after-using-listings-my-country-symbols-moved-to-words-front . If you could help me I would be appreciated.